# Why are some bc1 addresses 42 characters and others 62 characters in Base58?

Tags: address, segregated-witness, bech32-address

The length of bc1 Bitcoin addresses varies between 42 and 62 characters in Base58 encoding. What causes this difference in character count?

Answer (score 4):

P2WPKH (pay-to-witness-public-key-hash) addresses are 42 characters in length and P2WSH (pay-to-witness-script-hash) addresses are 62 characters in length (see [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100508/can-you-break-down-what-data-is-encoded-into-a-bech32-address)). `bc1` addresses also use [bech32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/e643d247c8bc086745f3031cdee0899803edea2f/bip-0173.mediawiki) encoding rather than base58.

For an explanation of why P2WSH addresses use larger hashes (256 bits) than P2WPKH addresses (160 bits) see this [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106140/why-are-p2wsh-addresses-larger-than-p2sh-addresses).

As Pieter states:

> P2PKH, P2WPKH, and P2SH addresses have 160-bit hashes in their addresses. For P2PKH and P2WPKH this is fine, as it only supports single-party construction. However, as P2SH supports multisig and other multi-party constructions, it means an ~2<sup>80</sup> attack is possible(*). Bitcoin typically has a 2<sup>128</sup> security target for attacks, so this is insufficient. That doesn't mean such a collision attack is practical - it's just far weaker than what the rest of the system provides, and as computing performance increases it may become feasible for well-funded parties.
>
> To address this, P2WSH introduced a multi-party-capable address that contains a 256-bit hash, so it has ~2<sup>128</sup> collision security.

Answer (score 1):

There are as of today 3 types of native segwit outputs:

- P2WPKH (pay to witness public key hash), where the output (and thus address) contains a 160-bit public key hash.
- P2WSH (pay to witness script hash), where the output (and thus address) contains a 256-bit script hash.
- P2TR (pay to taproot), where the output (and thus address) contains a 256-bit public key (not a hash!).

Addresses that contain a 256-bit value need 62 characters, while ones that contain a 160-bit value need just 42 characters, in bech32(m) encoding. Note that base58 is only used in P2PKH and P2SH addresses, which predate segwit (bc1) addresses.

Answer (score 0):

P2WPKH addresses have 42 characters, while P2WSH addresses have 62 characters.

This difference is due to the fact that P2WPKH bc1 addresses include a hash of the public key that is 20 bytes long, and P2WSH bc1 addresses include a hash of, let's call it, the redeem script that is 32 bytes long.

Comment: nit: It isn't encoded in hexadecimal (0-9 and a-f). A bech32 address contains letters beyond f e.g. x, y and z

Comment: @MichaelFolkson Totally agree. I accidentally wrote "hexadecimal characters". Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Those starting with bc1q are SegWit (42),
Those that start with the name bc1p are Taproot (62),
SegWit addresses are common and Taproot addresses are new

Comment: This is not entirely correct; P2WSH addresses are also 62 characters.