# collision attack on bitcoin p2sh

Tags: p2sh, attack

Book "mastering bitcoin" 3rd edition, on page 73, there is a statement as following:
"but there are organizations that expect to receive billions of dollars in bitcoins to
addresses generated by processes involving multiple parties, which could make the
attack profitable."

anybody can take an example to explain it? thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Birthday attack on P2SH](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54841/birthday-attack-on-p2sh)